# Nginx domain to subdomain redirection

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect all the traffic from `example.com` to `test.example.com` and I have written following rule for that :

```
server {
  server_name example.com; # change to match your URL
  return 301 $scheme://test.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

But its not working.

PS : I have install SSL certificate on the subdomain.

Comment: This server does not listen to https (i.e. port 403)

Comment: You mean port 443?

Comment: Yes 443. Stupid typo